# I'm getting TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] while using SMTP lib for the first time

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

I'm following a tutorial video and I made sure to type everything as the tutor typed but it still shows me the error msg.

Error msg: "TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

Please who knows what I can do to fix this

This is my code, a direct replica of what my tutor had, just with my own email details

```
import smtplib

my_email = "my.python@gmail.com"
my_password = "xxx"

with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com") as connection:
    connection.starttls()
    connection.login(user=my_email, password=my_password)
    connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email,
                        to_addrs="my.python@yahoo.com",
                        msg="Subject: Hello Buddy\n\n Here's me reaching out to you")
```

Comment: Please obfuscate your password and sensitive data. Never share your actual password for your e-mail account on any place on the internet. I would change the password immediately.

Comment: Gmail is not accepting connections on port 25 and your ISP probably does not allow you to try. Modern SMTP submission needs to use a separate port number; for Gmail, try 587. More generally, 587 with `STARTTLS` is the modern de facto standard, though some servers still support port 465 over TLS.

Comment: @user56700, thank you. those aren't my actual email address and password. I just typed something so i could make my point.

Comment: @tripleee I've made changed the port but i still get the same error

Comment: If you get the same error it means you still have the same problem. Perhaps your school's lab firewall prevents outbound traffic on port 587, or to Gmail.com generally.